# Logstash kv filter issue with value having comma

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

My kv filter's field split looks something like the follows -

field_split => ", "

The field_split is based on a comma followed by a space. But one of my values is a json string. And the output of logstash seems to ignore the value after it encounters the first comma.
Example - mdc field of the log looks something like:
abc=abcvalue request={"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}

What it parses it into is (the output is directed to elasticsearch):
"abc": "abcvalue"
"request": "{"key1":"value1""

How do I get the request field to be as follows?
"request": "{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly have json, you can match the json and parse it using the json filter.

For example:

```
filter {
  grok {
     match => ["request=(?<request_json>{[^}]+})"] // match from { to first } and put in request_json
  }
  json {
     source => "request_json"
     target => "request"
     remove_field => ["request_json"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding more information information - if the log line looks like this -- {"key": "value"}, the value is stored in a nested format in ES. However, if the log line looks like this {\"key\": \"value\"}  -- it gets stored as a String.. a json string.